# Set Drag Listener on SpannableString

Tags: javascript, android, drag-and-drop, spannablestring

Im trying to set an `OnDragListener` to certain words of a `TextView` using `SpannableString`. Im able to add an `OnClick` Listener by using `ClickableSpan`

by doing

```
hashText.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
```

So I figured I would try the same but replace `ClickableSpan` with `OnDragListener`.

I'm able to read the different drag events, but I have not been able to isolate the drag events to the specific words I choose, as Im able to do with `ClickableSpan`.

```
hashText.setSpan(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View targetView, DragEvent event) {
              int action = event.getAction();
              TextView targetVariable = (TextView) targetView;
              String textGetter;
              textGetter = targetVariable.getText().toString();
              // boolean actionDropOutside = (DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED != DragEvent.ACTION_DROP);
              switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:


                  Log.d(TAG, "DRAG STARTED");
                  break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                  ////create method that checks if text is empty if so lights up
                  //if (textGetter.equals("")) {
                    targetView.setBackgroundColor(CARD_SLECTED);
                    //lightupVariableCard(cardV);
                    Log.d(TAG, "DRAG ENTERED EMPTY TEXT");
                  //}

                  Log.d(TAG, "DRAG ENTERED" + targetVariable.getText().toString());
                  break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                  targetView.setBackgroundColor(CARD_UNSLECTED);
                  Log.d(TAG, "DRAG EXITED");
                  break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                  // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                  //if (textGetter.equals("")) {
                    TextView draggedView = (TextView) event.getLocalState();
                    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) draggedView.getParent();
                    targetVariable.setText(draggedView.getText());
                    owner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    targetView.setBackgroundColor(CARD_UNSLECTED);
                    //fabDisplayCounter++;
                    //displayFab();
                    Log.d(TAG, "DRAG DROPPED");
                  //}
                  Log.d(TAG, "DRAG NOT POSSSIBLE HERE");
                  break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
//                if (actionDropOutside == true){
//                    Log.d(TAG, "DRAG DROPPED OUTSIDE TRUE");
//                }
                  Log.d(TAG, "DRAG ENDED");
                  //default:

              }
              return true;
            }


          }, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), i);
          the_question.setText(hashText);
          the_question.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
          //the_question.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener(hashText.nextSpanTransition()));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a big expert in this field, never had to dig it out. But since you have no replies I try to give you some hint / direction.

I think what you need is a custom `MovementMethod`.

The android platform `MovementMethod` are managed here inside this package:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/java/android/text/method

Specifically this interface:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/method/MovementMethod.java

As you see it has a `onTouchEvent()` method.

`ClickableSpan` has an onClick method, but it only works because there's a `LinkMovementMethod` handling the touch events, looking for `ClickableSpan` and issuing the `onClick()` on them.

See:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/method/LinkMovementMethod.java

which extend:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/method/ScrollingMovementMethod.java

which extend
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/method/BaseMovementMethod.java

but this last is not really related with touches.

`ScrollingMovementMethod` use the class `Touch` to delegate the touch event handling, you can see this class here:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/method/Touch.java

Looking at the code very quickly I think you can extend the `LinkMovementMethod` and add the drag detection there. Then create a new `Span` type for the Drag and call the dragging methods inside it.

I know I did not gave you a solution but I hope I pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the Feedback. I'm not marking as an answer cause I don't wanna get yelled at by mods, but I went ahead and up voted to ensure you get points for your effort. I have tinkered a bit with you suggestion, but I've gone in a different direction in the meantime.As soon as I have time I'll revisit your suggestion and add the solution based on your answer. Thanks again

Comment: @user1446988 no problem mate, consider replying your own question with the solution you found, it can helps others or even your future self. If you try my suggestion let me know.